# ffmpeg mp3 encoder: how to set exactly 8.00 kbps bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, sox, lame

I want to produce constant-bitrate mp3 with bitrate 8.00kbps. I use this:
`ffmpeg -i q.wav -b:a 8k q.mp3`

But,instead of creating 8.00 kbps mp3, it creates 8.40 kbps file (or 8.41 or like that), as soxi informs:

Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:05.11 = 40896 samples ~ 383.4 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 5.37k
Bit Rate       : 8.41k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)

But I need 8.00 bitrate! I can easily produce it with `sox q.wav -C 8 q.sox.mp3`
Bit Rate       : 8.41k

How can I force ffmpeg produce mp3s with 8.00 k bitrate exactly?

Comment: mp3s made by `sox` or directly with `lame --encode` are not good for me, because they add padding in the beginning and end of file, while ffmpeg produce mp3s of exactly same length as original wavs

Answer (score 1):

should change sample rate to lower than 32000(availables: 22050 24000 16000 11025 12000 8000), sample format to `s16`(libmp3lame supported sample formats: s32p fltp s16p), and using `CBR`(with both `minrate` and `maxrate` the same) mode to compress, command is blow should do the trick:

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i q.wav -vn -c:a mp3 -minrate:a 8k -maxrate:a 8k -b:a 8k -sample_fmt s16p -bufsize 200K -ar 24000 o.mp3
```

Comment: unfortunately, this not work for me. still have 8.40 kbps file,comparing to 8.00 from sox and lame --encode

Comment: i tested this command on my computer, it's working. could you upload the file for me to test

Comment: @al.zatv This FFmpeg command works fine.  I was able to reproduce this on my machine as well.  Verifying the output file size vs the duration and doing the manual math shows that the bitrate is exactly correct.  I suspect that with such a short duration file you're testing with, the headers and tags and what not are being factored in.